# ASP-MVC: Different style-CSS for different languages

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

We want our site (ASP-MVC) to support different languages.
I'm having difficulties with applying different style-sheets to different languages (especially needed when I have a rtl (right to left) language such as Hebrew or Arabic vs a ltr (left to right) language such as English.

[image]

I have 2 css files whicj include the same css classes: EnglishSite.css, HebrewSite.css.
if the selected culture is en-US (as shown in image), I want to load EnglishSite.css, and all classes in site will take their styles from that file.
Otherwise, from the file HebrewSite.css.

There are similar questions to mine thorugh the site, but nothing worked for me, your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by applying a suffix to all my views (cshtml), for example:

```
class="center@(@Session["culture"])"
```

then I get centerhe-IL OR centeren-US and etc.
And I just use a single CSS file with both centerhe-IL and centeren-US declarations.